# Visual Studio throws exception -- simple OpenCV program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, exception

As I am completely new to OpenCV, I tried following a tutorial to capture video from a webcam. I used the following code:

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char** argc) {
    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture vid(0);    //0 if we only have one camera
    if (!vid.isOpened()) {  //check camera has been initialized
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open the camera";
        return -1;
    }

    while (vid.read(frame)) {
        imshow("webcam", frame);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, a window that shows the video feed opens, but it then almost immediately closes. I get this snippet from the Debug output:

```
SETUP: Device is setup and ready to capture.

Event: Code: 0x0d Params: 0, 0
Event: Code: 0x0e Params: 0, 0
Exception thrown at 0x000007FEFCBAA06D in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000026EB10.

SETUP: Disconnecting device 0
```

I don't know what could be wrong with my code or even how to begin debugging this. Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: Are you running in release or debug mode?

Comment: And have you stepped through your code with a debugger to see if at a particular line the exception is thrown?

Comment: This might be useful (and possible duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221213/cvexception-at-memory-location-error-occurs

Comment: @Javia1492 I was running in debug mode. I used the debugger and found that the exception was being thrown at the `imshow` line. I switched the while loop to a `while(1)` and read the image in it, but it didn't work until I also changed the waitKey line to be `waitKey(30) == 27`. I'm not sure why this worked. Thanks though!

Comment: Try copying the frame before using it.

Comment: @anon That seems to be a very specific change for it to work and not know why. You should try and understand what is happening.